# Who said Rebels are not necessarily dead?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, quotes

I remember hearing something a few months ago, in which a [perhaps] Disney executive said basically:

> Just because they were not in the Original Trilogy does not mean
>   they're dead.

This was in response to a question about why the Rebels characters did not appear anywhere else in canon.

Is this a real thing that I did not make up?  And if so, who said it?

Comment: Chopper, The Ghost and Hera at least are all mentioned / shown to be around in Rogue Onet. That's pretty close to the OT :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you were thinking of [this](http://io9.gizmodo.com/the-producer-of-star-wars-rebels-answers-your-burning-q-1768048083)?

> “Yoda says, ‘When gone I am, the last of the Jedi will you be.’ ‘Of the Jedi’ could be a group of Jedi. You don’t know... That’s not to say I believe there are a lot of Jedi running around by Return of the Jedi. I think there are Force-wielding people, but whether they subscribe to the Jedi philosophy of how you use the Force is another question... But fans deal in absolutes, like Sith.”
>
> He also points out a key line in the finale where Ahsoka says “I am no Jedi”—but still uses the Force and fights with two lightsabers.
>
> “She does say ‘I am no Jedi,’ very clearly,” Filoni explained. “So if she says that and Yoda later says ‘When gone am I, the last of the Jedi will you be,’ he’s definitely not talking about her. There were so many options of lines to give in this episode, and one of them along the way of the season was that Ahsoka would mention that Yoda wouldn’t think of her as a Jedi because she’s not, necessarily, practicing that path any more. She’s still in the Light Side, for sure, but she’s not a Jedi practitioner per se.”
>
> Whether or not that could cover the ultimate fates of Ezra and Kanan, Filoni would only hint.

Comment: Perhaps, but I was thinking the quote was much more directly related to the Rebels, rather than the Jedi.